# Javascript: what is the most efficient way to get a lower bound of zero?

Tags: javascript, performance

What is the most efficient (fastest) way to get a lower bound of zero?

Math.max(0, x) will work, returning 0 for any negative value of x.  However, my experience with Math.* is that there often is a far more performant trick to do it faster.  Anyone know of any in this case?

Bitwise tricks are fine; I always like finding real uses for those operators.  Anything that will return false, if x is negative, also is fine.

Edit
To clarify, if x is greater than 0, I want that value.  So I can't just do x < 0, as that will only give me true, not x.

Comment: In most cases, readability and maintainability of the code is way, way more important than performance.  None of the bit twiddling examples proposed as answers are very readable when someone else comes along to read your code some time from now (or perhaps even when you look at it again in a year).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way with your requirements is:

```
x > 0 && x
```

given that you are ok with the expression evaluating to `false` when `x` is 0 or negative. If you just want `false` when `x` is negative, you can do:

```
x >= 0 && x
```

Examples:

```
3 > 0 && 3;     // result: 3
-1 > 0 && -1;   // result: false
0 > 0 && 0;     // result: false

0 >= 0 && 0;    // result: 0
```

Answer (score 2):

`Math.Max(x, y)` is basically identical to e.g. `x > y ? x : y`. Returning `false` when `x` is negative should be equally simple: `return x < 0 ? false : x`

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerMinOrMax) section on min/max.

Here is their example in C...

```
int x;  // we want to find the maximum of x and y
int y;   
int r;  // the result goes here 

r = x ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y));
```

Which is trivial to adapt to JavaScript...

```
var x, y, r;

r = x ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y));
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xbDkw/).

However, unless you're in a tight loop (such as a game loop) and it was under performing due to `Math.max()` (and a simple ternary inline equivalent didn't give the performance required), I wouldn't use this bit fiddling trick. It's not obvious to anyone reading the code what it does and it would almost certainly need a comment to explain, while `Math.max()` is self-documenting in its name (to most programmers).

Comment: This is probably a good way to micro-optimize this case, but I would recommend running profiling in your target browsers to be absolutely sure it actually has a positive effect worth obfuscating the code into this.

Comment: @JaniHartikainen Exactly, check my last paragraph :)

Comment: Very true, though fun to know.  :D

Comment: I doubt you can use these kinds of C-targeted optimizations in higher level languages. I definitely second Jani's recommendation to profile this before _not_ using `Math`. Good implementations make these things as fast as possible, with inlining and internally implemented bithacks and the like.

Comment: Unless I'm implementing it wrong, trying 0 for either x or y, the ternary seems far faster than this bitwise trick, at least in Chrome 20.  http://jsperf.com/ternary-vs-bitwise  On that basis, for now at least, I'm giving the ternary answer the checkmark.

Comment: @BrianFreud I wouldn't doubt it. The best advice for optimisations is to check everything and don't assume, IMO.

Comment: 2021 update; x >= 0 && x is still quite a bit faster than the bitwise version.  Testing with the variable definition inside the test loop, it is only slightly faster (+2% faster), but if you define the variable(s) outside of the tests, to check only the raw speed of the comparison, x >= 0 && x comes out on average +115% faster.